# Blur an image before rending onto canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, gaussian, uiblureffect

I am trying to achieve a Gaussian blur for an image that I am moving on a canvas. Is there a way to blur the image before rendering it onto the canvas?

This image will not remain static and I will have to render multiple sizes of the same image so I can't just blur the source image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**You can quite easily get pre-rendered, blurred images of desired sizes!**

- create an offscreen canvas: `document.createElement('canvas');`
- draw your images in desired multiple sizes onto the offscreen canvas: `drawImage with sizing parameters`
- use a blur program to blur the whole offscreen canvas:

  http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
- use the offscreen canvas like a spritesheet and 'cut' whichever size image you need and draw the cut image to the onscreen canvas: again using `drawImage with sizing parameters`

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind, thats an interesting way to do it. Thanks!